# Custom Error Document for 3XX Redirects

Tags: php, perl, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When **redirect** is requested, **Apache** send its **default response**, which looks like this:

```
Location: http://192.168.1.1/test.txt
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>307 Temporary Redirect</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Temporary Redirect</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://192.168.1.1/test.txt">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I would like to customize this page (change HTML code, add some HTTP headers) to such redirection response, so in my `.htaccess` I used directive

```
ErrorDocument 307 /307.cgi
```

so my own script is called for serving the response.

I checked all environment variables, but I cannot find a way how to read/get a **new location** to which the original document should be **redirected**. Without that information I am unable to proceed. Where is such information available and how can I get it?

Comment: @Soma - The above default response from `Apache` is **exactly** how it is served, no fancy formatting.

Comment: Now sure if I fully understood your problem. Which new location you are trying to get?

Comment: @anubhava - If for example you have in `.htaccess` rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/to.txt [R=307,L,QSA]`, then my script `307.cgi` is called. I am able to get `from.txt` url information from environment variable(s), but I am unable to get `to.txt` destination url, to which it supposed to be redirected...

Comment: If you have custom handler defined for 307 then actual redirection will not even happen hence `/to.txt` won't be served at all.

Comment: @anubhava - **I have to serve such redirection with my** `307.cgi` **script.** Question is, where the requested destination url `to.txt` is recorded and how/if I can read it, so proper redirection is served.

Comment: Actually it is not recorded because of your custom handler in place. Your rule is effectively this: `RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ /307.cgi [L]`

Comment: @anubhava - How to serve custom 3XX error pages then..?!

Comment: @Ωmega I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: If you can explain what you're trying to do then I can certainly suggest some alternative ways to handle this.

Comment: @anubhava - I want to add some cookie headers for each redirection request. Redirection can come from anywhere, not just `.htaccess`. So, translation of existing rules in `.htaccess` is not solution, therefore I am looking for general way how to modify 3XX redirection response(s).

Comment: Well in that case you need to put some extra logic in `/307.cgi` If you are game for it I will post an answer below.

Comment: @anubhava - Show me your magic :)

Comment: Sorry not really a magic answer but a workaround type of answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, **it is not possible to obtain the "original" redirect target.**

The `ErrorDocument` directive essentially overwrites all redirections that match it's error code.

As @anubhava comments, the following two directives

```
ErrorDocument 307 /307.cgi
RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/to.txt [R=307,L,QSA]
```

Can be considered transformed to:

```
RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ /307.cgi [L]
```

**EDIT**

A solution would be to update all your 307 redirect rules to something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ /307.cgi?target=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/to.txt [L,QSA]
```

And make sure that your CGI script outputs a correct 307 HTTP header.

Comment: I didn't downvote but may be because this doesn't answer the question and just presents discussion above in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .htaccess code like this:

```
# these ErrorDocument lines to be used when your code sets these HTTP statuses
ErrorDocument 307 /handler.php?r=307
ErrorDocument 308 /handler.php?r=308
ErrorDocument 309 /handler.php?r=309
# ... more such ErrorDocument lines

# then use the same handler in your rewrite rules without R flag
RewriteRule ^abc\.txt$ /handler.php?r=307&source=$0&target=to.txt [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then in your `handler.php` have some code like this:

```
# access target file as:
if (isset( $_GET['target'] ))
    $target = $_GET['target'];

# access source file as:
if (isset( $_GET['source'] ))
    $target = $_GET['source'];

# set appropriate HTTP status IF coming from rewrite rules
if ( $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] != $_GET['r'] )
    http_response_code($_GET['r']);
```

**UPDATE:** This is how you can pseudo-invoke 307 error handler from your PHP code using PHP's `virtual` function.:

```
if (some-condtion) {
    http_response_code(307);
    $_GET['r']=307;
    $_GET['source']=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $_GET['target']='/some-url';
    virtual ( "/handler.php" );
    exit;
}
```

Now your `/handler.php` will get all the information to act upon i.e. it will have status code, source URI and target URI in `$_GET` array.

**PS:** Once control has been given over to PHP, it does not go back to Apache for error handling that's the reason you have to **forcefully call the error handler** as shown above.

Comment: This would **not work** for redirects originating outside of `.htaccess`, as `$target` is undefined...

Comment: That's the reason I have `isset( $_GET['target'] )` and may I know where would you be using `$target`?

Comment: ...and `QSA` may conflict with fixed parameters you use.

Comment: QSA might conflict, how? QSA is ONLY for `appending query parameters` not of replacing but you can just take it out if you don't care about existing query string.

Comment: Better would be use env then: `RewriteRule ^from\.txt$ 307.php [QSA,L,E=LOCATION:http://%{HTTP_HOST}/to.txt]`

Comment: Sure you can use env variable also but then QSA flag is useless.

Comment: And rather than separate handlers for separate status codes I was thinking of a generic handler that's why I suggested use of query string so that you can internally pass more than one variable.

Comment: Then my friend you're mistaken about use of QSA. WIthout QSA also you will get query string **as is** i.e. `a=1&target=2&r=3` QSA is ONLY needed when you are modifying query string in rewrite rule (as my rule is doing) for **appending existing query string** into new one.

Comment: Generic handler can be used, but additional env need tp be set then, to store status code...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44437/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mega)

Comment: Sorry I got busy and couldn't promptly update the answer. Check my update for a work around.